# High score Label not updating - UserDefaults and Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

The resource that I got this code from was written in Swift 3 and works appropriately. My app is written in Swift 4. I think that I may be missing something that is specific to Swift 4 but I can't figure out what it may be.

I have the appropriate outlets and variable ...

```
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var highScoreLabel1: UILabel!

var recordData: String!
```

`viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` are accounted for ...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
    let value = userDefaults.string(forKey: "Record")
    recordData = value

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
    let value = userDefaults.string(forKey: "Record")

    if (value == nil) {
        highScoreLabel1.text = "0"

    } else {

        highScoreLabel1.text = value
    }
}
```

I created a function that I though would work ...

```
func high score () {

    if gameMode == 0 {

        if recordData == nil {

            let savedString = scoreLabel.text
            let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
            userDefaults.set(savedString, forKey: "Record")

        } else {

            let score: Int? = Int(scoreLabel.text!)
            let record: Int? = Int(recordData)

            if score! > record! {

                let savedString = scoreLabel.text
                let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
                userDefaults.set(savedString, forKey: "Record")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make userDefaults global like your UILabels, don't do this `let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard` every time you use `userDefaults`

Comment: Read some about OOP

Comment: You have `recordData` which you set in `viewDidLoad`, why don't use `recordData` in `viewWillAppear` like `highScoreLabel1.text = recordData ?? "0"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The high score label is not updating because there is no code. The label is only set (once) in `viewDidLoad` / `viewWillAppear`.

I highly recommend to save the high score as `Int`. That avoids the optionals and the code can be reduced *dramatically*.

- Declare `recordData`

  ```
  var recordData = 0
  ```
- Delete the code in `viewDidLoad`. Loading the data once in `viewWillAppear` is sufficient.
- Replace `viewWillAppear` with

  ```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      // integer(forKey returns 0 if the key is not used yet
      highScoreLabel1.text = String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Record"))
  }
  ```
- Replace highscore with

  ```
  func highscore() {
      guard gameMode == 0, let score = Int(scoreLabel.text!), score > recordData else { return }
      recordData = score
      UserDefaults.standard.set(recordData, forKey: "Record")
      highScoreLabel1.text = String(recordData)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but highScoreLabel1 is still just staying  at "0". I checked the outlet and it's hooked up properly. I'm not sure what else to try. Any suggestions?

Comment: is `gameMode == 0` and can the text in  `scoreLabel` be converted to `Int`? Otherwise `highscore` exits silently. Is `highscore()` called at all?Set a breakpoint and check the values.

Comment: I have an `updateTimer` function where `gameMode` is set to `0`. I called `highscore()` there and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your answer and follow up.

Comment: vadian, A problem that I am currently encountering is that the `recordData` value DOES NOT remain saved if I leave the app and come back. It DOES remain saved if I play the game again without closing the app. If I close and reopen the app, ANY new `score` will replace the `recordData`, and thus, update the highScoreLabel1.text with the new score. This will occur even if the new `score` is a lesser value than the previously saved `recordData` value. So, basically UserDefaults is not persisting after the app is closed and re-opened. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code when you save

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  userDefaults.set(savedString, forKey: "Record")
}
```